# Fancybox как сделать ссылка на элементе?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Есть сайт с книгами, книги анимировано выдвигаются при наведении, и при клике открываются с помощью библиотеке fancybox, нужно на открытый элемент повесить ссылку на другую страницу. Причем на каждый элемент разную ссылку.
Можно ли это как то сделать встроенными функциями? Или есть какой-нибудь костыль хотя бы?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <section class="books">
    <div class="_container">
        <div class="books__block">
            <img src="/img/back.jpg" alt="" class="books__back-img">
            <div class="books__items-block bib-13 bib-12">
                <div class="second"></div>
                <div class="books__items bi-13">
                    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="/img/13/1_1.png" class="books__item bi13-1">
                        <img src="/img/13/1_1.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="/img/13/1_2.png" class="books__item bi13-2">
                        <img src="/img/13/1_2.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="/img/13/1_3.png" class="books__item bi13-3">
                        <img src="/img/13/1_3.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="/img/13/2_1.png" class="books__item bi13-4">
                        <img src="/img/13/2_1.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="books__items bi-12">
                    <a href="/img/12/3_01.png" data-fancybox="gallery2" class="books__item bi12-1">
                        <img src="/img/12/3_01.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="books__item bi12-2">
                        <img src="/img/12/3_02.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="books__item bi12-3">
                        <img src="/img/12/3_03.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="books__item bi12-4">
                        <img src="/img/12/3_04.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="second2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Будет здорово, если вы добавите код к своему вопросу. Так будет понятнее о чем речь

Comment: Добавил html и скрины сайта.
Нужно добавить на открытый элемент (2 скрин) ссылку, и нужно учитывать что их много, и на каждый своя ссылка